# How to get $attrs data of children DOM in a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-scope

Let say I have a controller and many children DOMs with their own `data` attributes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p data-test-val='Brian'>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

I want to access to the `data-test-val` like this

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $attrs) {
  $scope.name = $attrs.testVal;
});
```

However, it does not seem to work as `name` is empty.

http://plnkr.co/edit/V1Leit8U7r2k4CZDGaGa?p=preview

How to access any `data` attribute in children DOM of the same scope?

Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't manipulate the DOM into your controller, directive is the option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're messing up controllers with directives in terms of attribute acquiration.

directive:

```
.directive('directiveName', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
            // get $attrs stuff here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate directive named as "dataTestVal", then you can get an access to attributes of the tag.

Example Code:

```
<html ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <head>
    //required libraries, scripts
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="ExCtrl">
    <div data-testval data="person"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    angular.module('ExampleApp',[]);

     angular.module('ExampleApp")
      .controller("ExCtrl",function($scope){
         $scope.person = {
           name:"afd",
           age : 30
         };
     });
    angular.module('ExampleApp")
      .directive("dataTextval",function(){
         return{
           restrict:'A',
           scope:{
            data : '='
           },
           link:function(scope,element,attrs){
            //you can gain access to element and its attributes
            //scope.data is nothing but person details, which is declared in controller
           }
         }
       });


  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
$scope.name = ele.getAttribuete('data-test-val');
```

Comment: you're obtaining all paragraphs in the document. that doesn't look correct at all. moreover, ele is a collection, so getAttribute  is not a function.

Comment: Right I just give exemple but we can use id with getElementById it will be unique

Comment: in any case you're mixing concerns (templates/DOM and controllers) and using global elements like `document`. the correct place for that logic is a directive. you should be using angular's wrappers, like `angular.element` , `$window` etc. otherwise you might get async problems or break the data binding